# Controller Is not working in Ionic Framework

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on a Ionic based mobile application which does Basic Navigation through Templates

following is my Html Mark up and App.js Code

[image: Here are the Html Mark up]

[image: App.js Code]

now the first controller HomeCtrl Works fine but the Second controller i.e., OtherContrl doesn't work at all.

the $scope variable throws an Exception

Comment: that error are you getting from the console log?

Comment: you have a typo in the state of page2, its controller: not contrller

Answer (score 2):

Classic typo mistake, in your code you have the property contrller: instead of controller:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('page2', {
    url: '/page2',
    templateUrl: 'page2.html',
    controller: 'OtherContrl'
  }
```

Comment: @mayurmanudhanya no need, we all been there doing that. It its going to happen again :D